# Wordpress путь к изображением в css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Когда я задаю путь к изображению в HTML теге **img**, я использую:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>
```

Получается нечто подобное:

```
<img class="img" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?> /img/manual/element-1.png" alt="element">
```

А вот если у меня есть HTML тэг **div** и ему я задаю фон изображение с помощью CSS, как мне задать корректный путь к изображению?

```
div {
 background-image: url('../img/info/background-1.png');
}
```

Как быть в таком случае? Я же в данном случае не смогу использовать:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>
```

Comment: Если изображения в папке темы wp то ```div {
 background-image: url('../img/info/background-1.png');
}``` будет правильным

Comment: фон отобразился только тогда, когда я поменял путь на url('./img/info/background-1.png'), почему так?

Comment: Ааа, у меня стили находились в css, но после переноса на wp, файл стилей находится в корне, рядом с index.php